# OpenGL depth test is not working

Tags: c++, opengl, glut

I am trying to create a model using OpenGL, and I tried to enable depth testing.

I use these commands in my `main`:

```
glutInitDisplayMode(GLUT_RGB | GLUT_DOUBLE | GLUT_DEPTH);
glEnable(GL_DEPTH_TEST);
```

And this in my display:

```
glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);
```

I even tried adding:

```
glDepthFunc(GL_LEQUAL);
```

And it doesn't work. I can still see what I think are depth problems.
Here is a video showing the problem: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=OafrRH4Mzjc

- Note: In that video, the board is build right to left, top to bottom, so the first angle is OK, but any other angle is bad.

What am I missing?

---

**Edit**: Minimal example file of reproduction:

```cpp
#define _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS

#define SIZE_MOVES 17

#include <stdio.h>

/* Include the GLUT library. This file (glut.h) contains gl.h and glu.h */
#include <GL\glew.h>
#include <GL\freeglut.h>

static int  left_click = GLUT_UP;
static int  right_click = GLUT_UP;
static int  xold;
static int  yold;
static float rotate_x = 146;
static float rotate_y = -26;

int width, height;

GLfloat light_ambient[] = { 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0 };
GLfloat light_diffuse[] = { 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0 };
GLfloat light_specular[] = { 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0 };
GLfloat light_position[] = { 0, 5, -10, 0 };

GLfloat mat_specular[] = { 0.3, 0.3, 0.3, 1.0 };
GLfloat mat_shininess[] = { 1 };


// colors
const GLfloat colors[2][4] = {
    { 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0 }, //white
    { 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0 } //black
};

// rgb
const GLfloat rgb[3][4] = {
    { 1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0 },
    { 0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 1.0 },
    { 0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 1.0 }
};

void resetMaterial() {
    GLfloat c[] = { 1, 1, 1, 1 };
    glMaterialfv(GL_FRONT_AND_BACK, GL_AMBIENT_AND_DIFFUSE, c);
    glMaterialfv(GL_FRONT, GL_SPECULAR, mat_specular);
    glMaterialfv(GL_FRONT, GL_SHININESS, mat_shininess);
}

void drawSquare(int color) {
    glPushMatrix(); {
        glMaterialfv(GL_FRONT_AND_BACK, GL_AMBIENT_AND_DIFFUSE, colors[color]);

        glScalef(1, 0.5, 1);
        glutSolidCube(1);
    } glPopMatrix();
}

void drawBoard() {
    for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++)
        for (int j = 0; j < 8; j++) {
            glPushMatrix(); {
                glTranslatef(i + 0.5, 0, j + 0.5);
                drawSquare((i + j) % 2);
            } glPopMatrix();
        }
}

void drawAxes() {
    glBegin(GL_LINES); {
        glMaterialfv(GL_FRONT_AND_BACK, GL_AMBIENT_AND_DIFFUSE, rgb[0]);
        glVertex3f(-2, 0, 0); glVertex3f(5, 0, 0);
        glMaterialfv(GL_FRONT_AND_BACK, GL_AMBIENT_AND_DIFFUSE, rgb[1]);
        glVertex3f(0, -2, 0); glVertex3f(0, 5, 0);
        glMaterialfv(GL_FRONT_AND_BACK, GL_AMBIENT_AND_DIFFUSE, rgb[2]);
        glVertex3f(0, 0, -2); glVertex3f(0, 0, 5);
    } glEnd();
}

void letThereBeLight() {
    /*Add ambient light*/
    GLfloat ambientLight[] = { 0.2f, 0.2f, 0.2f, 1.0f };
    glLightModelfv(GL_LIGHT_MODEL_AMBIENT, ambientLight);

    /*Add positioned light*/
    GLfloat lightColor1[] = { 0.2f, 0.2f, 0.1f, 1.0f };
    GLfloat lightPosition1[] = { -8, 8, 5, 0.0f };

    glLightfv(GL_LIGHT0, GL_SPECULAR, lightColor1);
    glLightfv(GL_LIGHT0, GL_POSITION, lightPosition1);

    /*Add directed light*/
    GLfloat lightColor2[] = { 0.3, 0.3, 0.3, 1.0f };
    GLfloat lightPosition2[] = { 8, 8, -5, 1.0f };
    glLightfv(GL_LIGHT1, GL_AMBIENT, lightColor2);
    glLightfv(GL_LIGHT1, GL_POSITION, lightPosition2);
}

void display(void) {
    // Clear frame buffer and depth buffer
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);

    // Set up viewing transformation, looking down -Z axis
    glLoadIdentity();
    gluLookAt(0, 5, -15, 0, 0, 3, 0, 1, 0);

    letThereBeLight();

    resetMaterial();

    // Rotate view:
    glPushMatrix(); {
        glRotatef(rotate_y, 1, 0, 0);
        glRotatef(rotate_x, 0, 1, 0);

        glLightfv(GL_LIGHT0, GL_POSITION, light_position);

        glMaterialfv(GL_FRONT_AND_BACK, GL_AMBIENT_AND_DIFFUSE, colors[0]);

        glPushMatrix(); {
            glTranslatef(-4, 0, -4); // Move to center
            drawBoard();
        } glPopMatrix();

        drawAxes(); // For debuging
    } glPopMatrix();

    /* End */
    glFlush();
    glutSwapBuffers();
}

void mouseFunc(int button, int state, int x, int y) {
    if (GLUT_LEFT_BUTTON == button)
        left_click = state;

    xold = x;
    yold = y;
}

void motionFunc(int x, int y) {
    if (GLUT_DOWN == left_click) {
        rotate_y = rotate_y + (y - yold) / 5.f;
        rotate_x = rotate_x + (x - xold) / 5.f;
        glutPostRedisplay();
    }

    xold = x;
    yold = y;
}


void reshapeFunc(int new_width, int new_height) {
    width = new_width;
    height = new_height;

    glViewport(0, 0, width, height);
    glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
    glLoadIdentity();
    gluPerspective(50, width / height, 1, 20);

    glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);

    glutPostRedisplay();
}

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
    /* Creation of the window */
    glutInit(&argc, argv);
    glutInitDisplayMode(GLUT_RGB | GLUT_DOUBLE | GLUT_DEPTH);
    glutInitWindowSize(900, 600);
    glEnable(GL_DEPTH_TEST);

    glutCreateWindow("Chess");

    glEnable(GL_CULL_FACE);
    glCullFace(GL_BACK);

    glEnable(GL_POLYGON_SMOOTH);
    glEnable(GL_LINE_SMOOTH);

    glEnable(GL_LIGHTING);
    glEnable(GL_LIGHT0);
    glEnable(GL_LIGHT1);
    glShadeModel(GL_SMOOTH);
    glDisable(GL_COLOR_MATERIAL);

    glEnable(GL_BLEND);
    glBlendFunc(GL_SRC_ALPHA, GL_ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA);

    /* Declaration of the callbacks */
    glutDisplayFunc(&display);
    glutReshapeFunc(&reshapeFunc);
    glutMouseFunc(&mouseFunc);
    glutMotionFunc(&motionFunc);

    /* Loop */
    glutMainLoop();

    /* Never reached */
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Have you tried to remove the glDepthFunc and glEnable(GL_CULL_FACE) calls to remove possible culprits related to those?

Comment: @Bartvbl I did. Removing culling looks worse, as it also paints the back now. Removing the depth function does nothing

Comment: Then this goes beyond my knowledge of GLUT. May I instead recommend using something like GLFW and GLEW? They are modern bindings, which are being updated with new versions of OpenGL, and I believe with GLFW you get a depth buffer by default.

Comment: @Bartvbl If this was of my own initiative, sure. However, this is an academic assignment, and academia is always 10 years in the past. Thanks anyway

Comment: without seeing how you draw .... also what is in your projection matrix?

Comment: @Spektre I added the projection matrix definition. The drawing itself is around 200 lines, and I don't see how is relevant to a depth test question?

Comment: @Amit well it may be especially if you are manipulating matrices or forget to set Z coordinate or have some nasty bug somewhere ... like missing `glEnd()` call

Comment: @Amit just from a quick look you got many `push/pop`  pairs (many unnecessary) but I see no `glMatrixMode` calls before them !!! You are calling GLUT functions which may change (or not) actual matrix ...

Comment: @Spektre I know most are unnecessary, however, it really helps me to understand the structure. About the matrix mode, it is set in the reshape function (otherwise, nothing would be drawn) - I understand it is an unorthodox way, but this is my professor's instruction (we fork a file)

Comment: @Amit btw have you tried `glGetError` ?

Comment: @Spektre `glGetError` returns 0, `GL_NO_ERROR`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
gluPerspective(50, width / height, 0, 20);
                                   ^ wat
```

`zNear` needs to be [greater than zero](https://www.opengl.org/sdk/docs/man2/xhtml/gluPerspective.xml) (emphasis mine):

> Depth buffer precision is affected by the values specified for `zNear`
>   and `zFar`.  The greater the ratio of `zFar` to `zNear` is, the less
>   effective the depth buffer will be at distinguishing between surfaces
>   that are near each other.
>
> If `r = zFar / zNear` roughtly `log2(r)`  bits of depth buffer
>   precision are lost.  Because `r` approaches infinity as zNear approaches 0, **zNear must never be set to 0.**

---

**EDIT**: Given the newly-posted MCVE:

```
int main(int argc, char **argv) {
    /* Creation of the window */
    glutInit(&argc, argv);
    glutInitDisplayMode(GLUT_RGB | GLUT_DOUBLE | GLUT_DEPTH);
    glutInitWindowSize(900, 600);
    glEnable(GL_DEPTH_TEST);  // too soon

    glutCreateWindow("Chess");
    ...
}
```

It's just like [datenwolf said](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41936292): You're `glEnable()`ing before you have a current GL context (`glutCreateWindow()` creates the context and makes it current).

Don't call any `gl*()` functions until *after* `glutCreateWindow()`.

Comment: Thank you for pointing this out, I was not aware. However, i changed it to 1, and still I get the same result.

Comment: I added an edit. Started with an empty file, I added the main (settings), my variables, my lighting (otherwise everything looks white), a display function, and a rotatable view using mouse left-click drag, to spin the model and view the problem, just like in the video.

Comment: @genpfault looks like you got it ... (or datenwolf no idea why he was downvoted) havent seen his post until now ...

Comment: Thank you very much! I did try before to move it, however, I got an empty result screen. Now, I get the desired result.

Comment: Thank you so much! I was ripping my hair out over why the objects were not showing and I didn't know zNear cannot be 0.0.

Answer (score 0):

```
   public void onSurfaceChanged(int w, int h)
    {
        Matrix.frustumM(projectionMatrix,0,-(9f/18.5f),(9f/18.5f),-1f,1f,1.0f,1000f);
    }
```

I had to change my near clipping form 0.01f to 1.0f.